# Arduino - No Delay loop with wifi client failing

Tags: arduino

Anyone who feels the title is incorrect or misleading, please feel free to update it.

The issue I'm having is with my Uno R3 and WiFi Shield. I really can't share the exact source right now, but this will explain the issue pretty well:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>


char httpHost[] = "my.local.site.com";
IPAddress server(192,168,1,10);
int serverPort = 80;

char ssid[] = "myssid";
char password[] = "abcd123456";

int thingy = 0;

float lastTick = 0;
float tickInterval = 30000;

WiFiClient client;
boolean lastConnected = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  connectWifi();
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  float currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis >= (lastTick + tickInterval) || currentMillis < lastTick) {
    pollThingy();
    logUpdate();
    lastTick = currentMillis;
  }

  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (client.connected() == false && lastConnected == true) {
    Serial.println("-- Disconnected.");
    client.stop();
  }

  lastConnected = client.connected();

  if (lastConnected == true) {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
}

void connectWifi()
{
  int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("No WiFi Shield Found! Aborting!");
    while(true) { }
  }
  int i = 0;
  while(true) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to network: ");
    Serial.print(ssid);
    Serial.print(" Attempt #");
    Serial.println(++i);

    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    if (status == WL_CONNECTED) break;

    delay(10000);
  }

  if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connected!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed connecting! Aborting!");
    while(true) { }
  }
}

void pollThingy()
{
  thingy = digitalRead(2);
}

void logUpdate()
{ 
  Serial.println("Logging update: ");

  if (client.connected() == false) {
    Serial.print("-- Connecting to ");
    Serial.print(server);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(serverPort);

    if (client.connect(server, serverPort)) {
      Serial.println("     Connected!");
      client.print("GET /some/Uri/with/arguments?output=json HTTP/1.1");
      client.println(" HTTP/1.1");

      client.print("Host: ");
      client.println(httpHost);

      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
    } else {
      Serial.println("      Connection failed!");
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("-- Already connected... Skipping, this time...");
  }
}
```

Now the issue I'm having seems to be kinda crazy. This will work fine and log an update to the given endpoint every 30 seconds as expected. However, after about 2 hours it just stalls and fails to do anything again. I've confirmed by watching the serial monitor, which returns nothing other than the last expected `Serial.println()` statements, but there are no errors to be displayed or anything.

I haven't updated the firmware on the WiFi shield since I got it, and I honestly couldn't tell you what revision it's running. However, I feel like this is something else entirely and I just can't put my finger on it.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Please don't beat me up too much about my code style. This is just a first draft.

Comment: The 2 hour fail point is suspicious. 2 hrs, every 30 secs is 240x which is awfully close to 256. Could there be some 8 bit variable thats overflowing or something? BTW, what wifi library and shield are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You never close the connections you open.  You show a connection to a web server, but no Keep-Alive header.  The server should not be letting people sit on open connections just in case there is additional transactions to follow.  I would expect the server to drop the connections.

The Arduino code never closes a connection, it just keeps opening another every time it sees the server has disconnected.  At some point, the network stack runs out of handles to keep track of the debris.

For 30 s intervals, there is no reason to try to keep a connection open to a web server.  Add a

```
client.stop()
```

after the last println().

You could confirm what is going on with two tools:
- netstat (or similar) would tell you if the server is accumulating connections in CLOSE_WAIT or TIME_WAIT
- Wireshark would let you see if the server is trying to close the connection and not being acknowledged by the Arduino.

Comment: Aha, excellent. Thank you very much for pointing that out! I'll update my code and share the result.

Comment: Actually, that didn't work. It still ran for about 192 iterations then started failing the connection attempt. A re-flash resulted in the first iteration getting hung up and never disconnecting.

Comment: I added some logic inside the conditional of `loop()` to test if there was a "stale" connection before continuing. If there is, `stop()` is called on it and the loop function returns immediately. So far this seems to be working, but only time will tell if it really does solve the issue.

Comment: That logic didn't help, but I did remove the `read()` calls and it seemed to work okay. However, after 30 iterations it stalled again. Restarting the serial monitor got it going though. Is it possible that the `Serial.print()` and `Serial.println()` calls are causing issues?